# Patents in academic institutions

Tags: data-request, research

I am looking for a dataset containing information regarding patents owned by academic institutions with as many following fields as possible:

- name of the academic institution
- number of patents
- amount of revenue from patents

Ideally, broken down by field ( e.g., biology, or computer science ) and year.

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat difficult request because each of these parameters must be derived from government data.  Even number of patents is difficult b/c the names of patent owners vary widely because of spelling variation/errors.  Also the definition of "academic institution" is somewhat ambiguous.  Amount of revenue from patents is also not something the government tracks and may be untrackable.

All that being said, http://www.patentsview.org/web/ has free access to somewhat out dated patent data via API for free.  If you want up to date data you could use a service like [IP Street](http://www.patentsview.org/web/).

Full disclosure, I am the head of product at IP Street so I deal with questions like this a lot.  Reach out if you are interested in getting access.  It's free to academic

Answer (score 1):

Another potential source would be **The NBER U.S. Patent Citations Data File** ([original data from NBER Site](https://data.nber.org/patents/) and [updated data](https://sites.google.com/site/patentdataproject/Home/downloads)).  As mentioned in the previous answer, the name of the patent holder is present but one would have to manually match this field to a list of academic institutions.  The only desired variable not present is a measure of revenue generated from the patent.  I'm not familiar with the standard in patent valuation methods so I'd imagine there are [several alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_valuation).

Data Citation:

> Hall, B. H., A. B. Jaffe, and M. Trajtenberg (2001). "The NBER Patent
>   Citation Data File: Lessons, Insights and Methodological Tools." NBER
>   Working Paper 8498.